# Are DAG-based crypto currencies as secure as proof-of-work based blockchains?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

A key feature of blockchain based cryptocurrencies is that they provide inherently secure systems that don't rely on trusted third parties. The newer DAG-based cryptos like Byteball are being touted as superior to blockchains because they have faster transaction times and eliminate the need for miners. However, these cryptos use something called "trusted witnesses" to resolve double spend conflicts. Isn't this inherently less secure than a true trustless system like Proof of Work? I thought that the whole point of a blockchain was to provide intrinsic security without the need for trusted third parties.

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it will be closed as off-topic here. You may be able to get help on [bitcoin.se].

Comment: Probably not since altcoin questions are discouraged on [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

adversaries may purposely set up 4 nodes, Alice1, Alice2, Bob1 and Bob2. Alice1 and Alice2 has the same account, so is Bob1 and Bob2.
Later, adversaries make a transaction Alice1 send $1 to Bob1 (from a separate node) and forcibly maintain this record in Alice1 and Bob1.
and Alice2 sent $2 to Bob2. (from a separate node) and forcibly maintain these records in Alice2 and Bob2. 
Now, which one will the representative choose? In POW, you can only choose 1.